# expo-screen-orientation orientation lock causes crash when opening a modal

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-screen-orientation

Trying to figure out how to create a game with Expo in landscape, and noticing that if I've added a landscape orientation lock it crashes on iOS when trying to open modals.  Note that it actually works fine if you dont include the useEffect.  However, the initialOrientation doesn't seem to work to begin with...

Wondering if anyone else has seen this

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

App.js

```
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';
import { Animated, Modal, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
        async function changeScreenOrientation() {
            await ScreenOrientation.lockAsync(ScreenOrientation.OrientationLock.LANDSCAPE);
        }

        changeScreenOrientation();
    }, []);
    const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => setModalVisible(true)}>
                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Open</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Modal animationType='slide' transparent={true} visible={modalVisible} onRequestClose={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
                <View style={styles.centeredView}>
                    <View style={styles.modalView}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
                            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Close</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#f0f0f0', // Light background color for better visibility
    },
    button: {
        borderRadius: 20,
        padding: 10,
        elevation: 2,
        marginTop: 15,
        backgroundColor: '#2196F3',
    },
});
```

app.json:

```
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "Player",
        "slug": "Player",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true,
            "requireFullScreen": true
        },
        "android": {
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
            }
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
        },
        "plugins": [
            [
                "expo-screen-orientation",
                {
                    "initialOrientation": "LANDSCAPE"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find a soution? I'm stuck with the same issue

Comment: Nope, still searching for solutions.  For now I am just using a useState to just pause the game and conditionally render a view over the screen, which is obviously suboptimal compared to being able to use the default modal.